# Creating a unique index on a shared throughput collection in Cosmos DB using the Mongo API

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have tried following the instructions from the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing#creating-unique-indexes) to create a unique index on a partitioned collection:

```js
db.runCommand({shardCollection: db.coll._fullName, key: { university: "hashed"}});

db.coll.createIndex( { "student_id" : 1, "university" : 1 }, {unique:true})
```

The collection is created, however the `createIndex` command always returns the following error:

> The unique index cannot be modified. To change the unique index, remove the collection and re-create a new one.

I have, using the emulator, tried this on databases with provisioned throughput on and off with the same result .

Has anyone been able to do this?

Comment: Have you enabled the latest MongoDB protocol (which can be found in the 'preview features' blade)? You probably need to do that, to support compound indexes. Have you tried with a single-property index? Note: I was successfully able to execute the commands you shared, with a newly-created MongoDB database+collection.

Comment: As below, the issue is the emulator doesn't recognise the command

Answer (score 3):

Follow @David's words, i also tested your commands successfully. Based on the statement in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing#creating-unique-indexes):

> Currently, unique indexes can be created only when the collection is
>   empty (contains no documents).

You could check whether your collection is empty.Another point is that maybe sometimes emulator have different behaviors with could real version.So, you could try to execute commands with official db.

Comment: It seems to be this exactly, the emulator doesn't have the same behaviour

Comment: @Sam Yes,maybe you could try official version. If you think my answer helps you,you could mark it.

Comment: How do you go about to do it using the emulator? When I try to run `db.<collection>.createIndex(<args>)`, I get "ERROR: createIndex is not implemented on this tool, please use your favorite Mongo framework or third party tools":

When I use Mongo Compass however, I get the error that the original post states.

Comment: I finally got it to work. Can't believe it's such a cumbersome process, but I got it to work by manually creating the collection from scratch from Mongo shell:

```
use <database>
db.runCommand({customAction: "CreateCollection", collection: "<collection>", offerThroughput: <RU>, indexes: [{key: {<indexField>: 1}, name: "<indexField>", unique: true}]});
```